# Instagram api python

Tags: python, api, instagram

Сделал всё как тут описано https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram
Но при подключение instagram в python выдаёт такое No name 'client' in module 'instagram'.
В папке site-package все файлы имеются, удалял и устанавливал по новой без результата.

Comment: в документации этого API - написано, если у вас возникли проблемы (как у вас), то введите sudo pip install --upgrade six

Comment: Как я понимаю у меня обновлено Requirement already up-to-date: six in c:\users\xzc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (1.15.0)

Answer (score 0):

pyCurl нужной версии для instagram-python не устанавливался на python>2.7 версии, переустановив python модуль установился успешно как и pycurl